Which of these tables represents a function?
This question comes from a GED prep site and the wording of this confuses me and I’m hoping someone can shed some light.
Here’s a picture of the question with the corresponding tables. Then they ask which of the tables is not a function.

I know that they want me to conclude that it is C because a function can only be mapped from domain A to domain B so that domain A has a unique set values but that multiple values in A can map to a single value in B.
I think my confusion comes from the automatic assigning of domain A to $x$ and domain B to $y$. Isn’t the assignment of $x$ and $y$ arbitrary? Like it could represent dimensions or a dependent and independent variable but do we really know that just from a table of $x$ and $y$? Or is $x$ always domain A which is the one that is mapped to Y, domain B?
The only argument I can think of for why you can have repeated values in $y$/domain B but not in $x$/domain A is because then the slope would not exist.
Shouldn’t this question come with the caveat of specifically asking for the case $f(x)$. Couldn’t your function be f(y) and then another table would be valid?
Do I understand functions and axes correctly?

It is usually understood that a function defined in tabular form has the domain on the left and the codomain on the right. In general, you are correct. Table $A$, for example, represents a perfectly good function if the $y$ values are assumed to be in the domain and the $x$ values are assumed to be in the codomain. Likewise, table $C$ does not represent a function if the domain is chosen to be the $y$ values because $y=-4$ would get mapped to two different values.

You are perfectly correct in what you say. You can have functions $x=f(y)$ just in the same way that you have functions $y=f(x)$. But there are lots of standard assumptions in the human language in general, and in mathematics in particular, that makes communication possible. If you have to specify all the data every time you write a question/problem, you need go back to the definition of every single word you are using (too long statements!).
Of course, these assumptions depend on the context.
Having said that, probably, in the context of GED or high school,they are considering the assumption $y=f(x)$. But that won't be longer valid in more advanced mathematical contexts.
